# Unable to add GPU(approved quota) to a previously created VM instance on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gpu, google-compute-engine

I have set up an instance for my research project on GCP, with standard 8 vCPU cores. Upon adding GPUs during its creation I was asked to request quota to add GPUs. I went ahead and requested for GPU quota(status: approved.) I read up that GPUs could be added to an existing instance therefore I created a VM instance with the a standard 8 vCPU config. This was done to set up work-space as I was waiting for the GPU quota to be approved.

Now that the GPU quota is approved, I am trying to add GPU my instance. 
[GPU quota successfully approved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e96xw.png)

I find that the "Add GPU" option is unhighlighted. 
["Add GPU" not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Kpi.png)

The documentation says I cannot set up GPUs on shared core CPUs and that my instance needs to Terminate on host maintenance. I have made sure to match the criteria. 
[Terminate VM instance on host maintenance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uuc1w.png)

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You don't have any category or vendor tags like VM or google compute ... so it's unlikely you're going to get a great answer ... though you might have better luck writing a support ticket inside the system you're working on for a definitive answer

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, not all regions have GPUs for the Compute Engine API on GCP.

[Available resources for regions and zones](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/#available)

Not all regions have access to the GPU resources. My instance was created in europe-west3 which does not have access to GPUs. To solve this issue I have to create an instance in one of the zones where GPUs are available. Moving the instance to a region with GPUs solved the problem.